# How to solve onDoubleTapListener and OnGesture error?

Tags: android

I am relatively new to android studio and would like to ask how do you solve an error: identifier expected. I know you would need a pair of brackets but do not know what to put inside them. 
`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener()
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener()
                }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to implement `OnGestureListener` and `OnDoubleTapListener`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener
{

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector; 

    // Called when the activity is first created. 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Instantiate the gesture detector with the
        // application context and an implementation of
        // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        // Set the gesture detector as the double tap
        // listener.
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    { 
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event)
    { 
       Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString()); 
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) 
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString()); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) 
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll: " + e1.toString()+e2.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event)
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress: " + event.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: After I added the above example in `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener
{` it got rid of the "identifier expected" error, but it now says that "Error:(23, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onFling(MotionEvent,MotionEvent,float,float) in OnGestureListener" Any ideas? @pez

Comment: @15Y1JEIFFELCHONGSHIANGYIH Are you sure you added everything in my answer? The method `onFling(MotionEvent,MotionEvent,float,float)` is there, right after `onDown()`.

Comment: Okay now I made sure everything was there, however, the `DEBUG_TAG` still has some problems. ie. "Error:(207, 15) error: cannot find symbol variable DEBUG_TAG"

Comment: @15Y1JEIFFELCHONGSHIANGYIH `DEBUG_TAG` is at the very top of the class. It's just a String to mark what you're logging. `private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";`

Comment: I have another inquiry about setupDrawer. I have this string of code: `private void setupDrawer(){
        mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
` The drawer_open and drawer_close variables have an error where they cannot find symbol variable "Error:(83, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable drawer_open" & "Error:(83, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable drawer_close"

Comment: @15Y1JEIFFELCHONGSHIANGYIH They're just strings. You can add them in `res/values/strings.xml` or just replace `R.string.drawer_open` with `"drawer_open"` and `R.string.drawer_closed` with `"drawer_closed"`.

Comment: I need help with the 3 codes below: `if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }`, `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and
    `public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Options!");
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }`

Comment: Reasons are cannot resolve objects and already defined in class